# Why can I connect to the docker daemon with sudo, but not root?

Tags: docker, sudo, root, nixos

Consider the following sequence of commands. When I try to connect to the docker daemon as a regular user, or root, I can't. When I use sudo (both as a regular user and root) I can. Why is this?

```
[john@mb:~]$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[john@mb:~]$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                PORTS                                                      NAMES
150fdfe05f3b   nicolargo/glances:latest-full   "/bin/sh -c '/venv/b…"   3 days ago   Up 2 days             0.0.0.0:61208->61208/tcp, :::61208->61208/tcp, 61209/tcp   glances
83c656bf1863   filebrowser/filebrowser         "/filebrowser"           3 days ago   Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                      filebrowser

[john@mb:~]$ su root
Password: 

[root@mb:/home/john]# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[root@mb:/home/john]# sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS                PORTS                                                      NAMES
150fdfe05f3b   nicolargo/glances:latest-full   "/bin/sh -c '/venv/b…"   3 days ago   Up 2 days             0.0.0.0:61208->61208/tcp, :::61208->61208/tcp, 61209/tcp   glances
83c656bf1863   filebrowser/filebrowser         "/filebrowser"           3 days ago   Up 2 days (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                      filebrowser
```

Comment: How did you install docker? This looks like maybe a rootless install, but as root while under your user profile.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` resets environment. `su` does not.

Your user has evidently set the `DOCKER_HOST` variable to `unix:///run/user/1000/docker.sock` or has it in Docker configuration file. `grep`for `docker.sock` may be a good way to find it.